# JQuery case format

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
    <option value="345345">City Name 1</option>
    <option value="342005">City Name 2</option>
    <option value="300005">City Name 3</option>
    <option value="345111">City Name 1000</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var city = 'CITY NAME 384';
$("#cities option:contains(" + city + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

How can I select the option containing '***CITY NAME 384***' when the combo options will only offer '***City Name 384***'? (same string, different cases)
I was thinking of something like:

```
$("#cities option.toLowerCase():contains(" + city.toLowerCase() + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But it did not work.
I can't set the var name manually as it come from an outer source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a manual filtering of the selected option using [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var city = 'CITY NAME 384'.toLowerCase();
$("#cities option").filter(function () {
    return city == $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase()
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u8DNp/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#cities option.toLowerCase()").filter(function() { return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == city.toLowerCase() }).attr('selected', 'selected');
```